# Display Current Baseline with Cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

How can I view the baseline on which the current view is based?

I could find information only on how to view the currently recommended baseline for a stream

```
cleartool desc -fmt %[rec_bls]CXp stream:myProject_Int@\myProject_pvob
#This gives the currently recommended baseline for the stream
```

Basically what I am looking to do is update the Build Notes.
1. Determine the baseline on which the last rebase was done
2. Determine the current recommended 
3. Make a list of activities that have been delivered.

I was able to find the information to do steps 2 and 3, but not for step 1. Maybe I'm not using the right term for the search...please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could describe the Stream in order to get the foundation baselines:

```
cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
```

(knowing that you can get the stream name of the current view
with a simple "`cleartool lsstream -cview`" executed anywhere within your view).

Comment: @sonofdelphi: oops, a bit late: yes, those commands work in snapshot or dynamic views.

Answer (score 3):

Building on the excellent answer from [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898359/3803219), from anywhere within your view you can combine the steps into a one liner.

```
cleartool lsstream -cview -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp"
```