# Clearcase UCM - How to get the config spec of a given baseline?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, baseline, config-spec

I'd like to set-up a non-UCM clearcase (read only) view for debugging an issue reported on a old baseline  which was delivered to customer.

How to view/retrieve/generate the config spec of the old baseline? so that I use this config spec to create a non-UCM clearcase view for debugging the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The config spec is simple:

```
 element * baseline_id
 element * /main/0
 element * /main/LATEST
```

(note that the `/main/0` is important, especially in a multi-component vob, for the initial version of the component is registered in `/main/0` when a new component is created)

What you need to find out is:

- what is the baseline id? (which can differ from the baseline title).
  See "[Display Current Baseline with Cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898359/6309)".
  You can for instance describe the stream to get the foundation baselines id:

  ```
  cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
  ```
- is the baseline a full or an incremental one? See "[What is the difference between Full baseline and Incremental baseline in Clearcase UCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309)".
  If it is an incremental one, you need first to promote the baseline to a full one.

  ```
  ct chbl -full -nc baseline:abaselinexxx.yyyy@\apvob
  ```

Comment: VonC, Thanks for the detailed answer and references.

Comment: My baseline type is 'full' only but it's for the stream (not for the VOB). So put the actual VOB labels (e.g: element * <baseline_ID>.xyz) in the config spec then I am able to get view loaded.

Comment: @user3214692 "vob label"? `<baseline_ID>.xyz` is not a vob label, it is a baseline id. You don't need a vob label, unless you are working with a snapshot view (which requires indeed "loading"), in which case you need to add a load rule (which will use the vob label)

Comment: I got those dependent VOB baselines (earlier I called it as labels) using "cleartool desc -l baseline:<baseline_id>@\<component_name>". This command lists the VOBs baselines which it depends on. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think a much simple solution is to create a stream based on the baseline you have. That way you can even write into it without interfering nothing and even to save you changes in CC

It's very simple to create a stream based on a baseline, click the "advanced" option when creating stream as usual.

Enjoy,
Eli.